# Как вставить шрифтовую иконку FontAwesome через css?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Не могу вставить иконку font awesome через css

```css
.header__arrow::before {
  content: "\f107";
  display: block;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<button type="button" class="header__arrow"></button>
```

Comment: а как пытаетесь вставить? код приведите

Comment: <button type="button" class="header__arrow"></button>

Comment: .header__arrow::before {
 content: "\f107";
 display: block;
 font-family: FontAwesome;
}

Comment: Отредактировал сниппет кода. Все работает. Может вы не подгрузили css font awesome?

Comment: Спасибо большое, все сработало! Я просто подключал пятую версию.

Comment: тогда удалите свой вопрос, чтоб не висел